# displaying more information by clicking onlink button more

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I have a jquery function where upon clicking on a more link I display more information of a specified summary.
I am relatively new to jQuery and I was hoping for a pointer as to where I am going wrong as it is not working as it is.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#more').on("click", function () {
      "$('#more').hide(); $('#content').show();"
    });

});
```

This is my C# code on code behind

```
 topicGenerator.InnerHtml += summary.Substring(1, 100);
 topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<a href='#' id='more'> more...</a>";
 topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<div id='content' style='display:none;'>"+summary+  </div>";
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will swap between show and hide and change the `<a>`  to less then again more

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#more').click(function () {
          $('#content').toggle();
          if($('#more').html()=='more...'){
          $('#more').html('less...');
    }else{
          if($('#more').html()=='less...'){
          $('#more').html('more...');
    }      
    }

        });

    });
```

Comment: and give some attention to the space you left before more... in the html

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
"$('#more').hide(); $('#content').show();"
```

to

```
$('#more').hide(); 
$('#content').show();
```

You don't need to wrap these statements in `"quotations"`.

You could also condense `.hide()` and `.show()` into `.toggle()`:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#more").click(function(){
    $("#content").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Tdcn/).